# unable to get access token from sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am trying to get the access token from share point using following steps -

URL - POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf

Headers -

Accept:application/json; odata=verbose
Content-Type:text/xml; charset=utf-8

Request url -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</a:Action>
        <a:ReplyTo>
            <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf</a:To>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <o:UsernameToken>
                <o:Username>myusername</o:Username>
                <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</o:Password>
            </o:UsernameToken>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <t:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
            <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
                <a:EndpointReference>
                    <a:Address>https://mysharepoint.sharepoint.com</a:Address>
                </a:EndpointReference>
            </wsp:AppliesTo>
            <t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey</t:KeyType>
            <t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType>
            <t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion</t:TokenType>
        </t:RequestSecurityToken>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

and I am getting response -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wst="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust" xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <S:Header>
        <wsa:Action S:mustUnderstand="1" wsu:Id="Action">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RSTR/Issue</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:To S:mustUnderstand="1" wsu:Id="To">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security S:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                <wsu:Created>2019-12-13T10:20:03.4038542Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2019-12-13T10:25:03.4038542Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </S:Header>
    <S:Body xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <wst:RequestSecurityTokenResponse xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wst="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
            <wsp:AppliesTo>
                <wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
                    <wsa:Address>https://mysharepoint.sharepoint.com</wsa:Address>
                </wsa:EndpointReference>
            </wsp:AppliesTo>
            <psf:pp xmlns:psf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Passport/SoapServices/SOAPFault">
                <psf:reqstatus>0x8004882c</psf:reqstatus>
                <psf:errorstatus>0x80045b00</psf:errorstatus>
            </psf:pp>
        </wst:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

What is the errorstatus 0x80045b00 ? I am not getting any reference of it.

I am following the steps mentioned in the blog

https://paulryan.com.au/2014/spo-remote-authentication-rest/

Comment: I am able to get security token successfully using this request body, please double check your username, password and site address

Comment: Do you have any idea about  0x80045b00 error code ?

Comment: Don't have idea about that must be something about invalid SOAP request. i get the same error code, if i enter the incorrect site address.

Comment: I have verified url and creds  from Azure AD

Comment: Have you tried send SOAP request using postman?

Comment: yes, I have tried that too

Comment: Are you able to access the site[https://[yoursharepoint].sharepoint.com/ in browser?

Comment: yes I can but it needs sign in and adfs login too

Comment: I have the same problem. I have not found the error codes explained. But I assume it is because my domain requires two-factor-login (in this case a phone callback) Need a workaround myself

Comment: @RakeshChouhan how did you fixed it, I am getting the same error status and I don't have 2FA